# Use VBA to select an Excel slicer value

Tags: excel, vba, loops, slicers

I am trying to go through a slicer in VBA, this is my code:

```
ActiveWorkbook.SlicerCaches("Slicer_Customer_Name1").ClearManualFilter 'Opens the slicer we want to focus on
    With ActiveWorkbook.SlicerCaches("Slicer_Customer_Name1")
            For countCustomer = 1 To 100

            Sheet4.Cells(countCustomer, 3) = Sheet3.Cells(5, 1)
            prevCustomer = countCustomer - 1
                If countCustomer > 1 Then 
                .SlicerItems(countCustomer).Selected = True 
                .SlicerItems(prevCustomer).Selected = False 
                End If
            Next countCustomer

    End With
```

What I want to do is go through the slicer and print out the value in cell A5 for each different filtered value. I need it to complete code for a project where this is just the foundation.

Comment: What does the code do at present? If you can narrow down the difficulty you're having, that may help readers help you.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: Right now `Sheet4.Cells(countCustomer, 3) = Sheet3.Cells(5, 1)` is assigning the value from `Sheet3!A5` (for the *first* iteration of the loop) to `Sheet4!A3`, but it sounds like you might be looking to have it the other way around...? If so, try reversing the sides of that function. Otherwise, please provide additional information so that we can assist.

Comment: It is the right way around, it is currently giving a totally incorrect output, when I click on the slicer manually and see what that value should be, it is giving me something else... Any ideas?

Comment: Also A5 is an item in the pivot table